# How to divide between a decimal and double

Tags: c#

I need to divide 282.48 (constant) by a decimal variable (consumption) so i try

```
Console.WriteLine("Your fuel consumption rate is " + Math.Round(consumption, 2) + "lt/100km or " + (282.48/consumption) + "gpm");
```

but visual studio tells me

> / cannot be applied to "double" and "decimal"

What do i do to make this work > (282.48/consumption)

Comment: Please try to research your problem(s) before posting copying your quote into google produces 9.7 million results for me... the top of which are duplicates..

Answer (score 1):

In c# by default decimal constants are `double` datatype unless you explicitly specify one. You can cast the number to `decimal` or use `M` suffix which refers decimal.

For instance the following should work

```
282.48M/consumption
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Console.WriteLine("Your fuel consumption rate is " + Math.Round(consumption, 2) + "lt/100km or " + (282.48/(decimal)consumption) + "gpm");
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
decimal consumption = 282.48m;
Console.WriteLine("Your fuel consumption rate is " + Math.Round(consumption, 2) + "lt/100km or " + (282.48m / consumption) + "gpm");
```

mark `282.48` as a decimal value by adding a `m` - `(282.48m / consumption)`

Answer (score 0):

cast  double variable to decimal

```
    decimal consumptionValue = System.Convert.ToDecimal(consumption);
    Console.WriteLine("Your fuel consumption rate is " + Math.Round(consumption, 2) + "lt/100km or " + (282.48/consumptionValue ) + "gpm");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [7.7.2 Division operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) documentation, there are 3 usage for floating point and decimal divisions.

```
float operator /(float x, float y);
double operator /(double x, double y);
```

and

```
decimal operator /(decimal x, decimal y);
```

Your division tries to `double / decimal` (because without any suffix, `282.48` is `double` by default) which is not available.

You can explicitly cast your consumption to double as;

```
(282.48 / (double)consumption)
```